# Когда я открываю интерактивную оболочку какое виртуальное окружение используется?

Tags: python, python-3.x

При открытие интерактивной оболочки через терминал командой `python3` какое будет использоваться виртуальное окружение?

Comment: То, в контексте которого Вы находитесь. Если Вы не находитесь в контексте виртуального окружения, то будет вызван системный интерпретатор.

Comment: Системный - это /usr/bin/pythonX ?

Comment: Если говорить про линукс

Comment: Скорее всего, да.

Comment: Для начала, что бы вам ответить на эти вопросы, нужно видеть полный ввод и вывод командной строки вместе с приглашениями к вводу.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так посмотреть исполняемый файл и папки с модулями - что и есть виртуальное окружение в совокупности

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/local/bin/python3.9'
>>> 
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```